# Kotlin flow sequential asynchronous processing

Tags: kotlin, asynchronous, future, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I have a `flow` (`MutableSharedFlow`, if it's relevant) and I have potentially expensive operation that I would like to execute asynchronously, while still maintaining the order. I achieved what I wanted using `CompletableFuture`:

```
private val threadPoolSize = 5
private val threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadPoolSize)

fun process(flow: Flow<String>) = flow
    .map { CompletableFuture.supplyAsync({ expensiveHandle(it) }, threadPool) }
    .buffer(threadPoolSize)
    .map { it.get() } // block current thread
    .flowOn(threadPool.asCoroutineDispatcher())
```

Thanks to combination of offloading to thread pool, fixed size `buffer` and *thread blocking* `CompletableFuture#get`, this code works to my expectations - up to `threadPoolSize` events are processed in parallel, and emitted to the flow in the order they were received.

When I replace `CompletableFuture#get` with extension function `CompletableFuture#await` from `kotlinx.coroutines.future` and use `flow` or `async` instead of `CompletableFuture#supplyAsync`, the messages are no longer processed in parallel:

```
fun process(flow: Flow<String>) = flow
    .map { 
        runBlocking {
            future { expensiveHandle(it) } // same behaviour with async {...}
        }
    }
    .buffer(threadPoolSize)
    .map { it.await() }
    .flowOn(threadPool.asCoroutineDispatcher())
```

Can I do equivalent code using coroutines/suspending functions?

Comment: I don't think `buffer` is doing what you described. It creates a separate coroutine for the code below it, but it is not running the first `map` call in parallel. It's running the below `.map` function in parallel with the first `.map` call on later items in the flow. Since the first `.map` call is non-blocking, there's not much gained by buffering.

Comment: Aha, I see, thank for pointing it out - in that case the parallelism comes solely from offloading the work to the thread pool, right @Tenfour04?

Comment: I've not ever mixed Java concurrency with Kotlin coroutines, so I don't want to guess without testing and tell you something wrong. But I think so. The CompletableFutures automatically start running when you create them, so they're all running in parallel. You can get similar behavior in a suspending way using `async`.

Comment: That looks right to me except for passing a parameter into the `buffer` call. There only needs to be a buffer of 2, which I think is typically the default.

Comment: So after removing the buffer and using 2 threads in the pool instead of 5, I didn't get to run the expensiveHandle on both thread, but only one. I guess the other one was blocked   (perhaps in the await?) as the pool is also used in the flowOn. Also, I think I found the way to do the desired think - see my edit. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem wasn't the `future` itself, but the surrounding `runBlocking`. When using custom `CoroutineScope` with the thread pool as underlying dispatcher, the code is working as expected (mind the change of `get` to `await`, and also I used `async` instead of `future` as it's in the core coroutine library):

```
private val threadPoolSize = 5
private val threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadPoolSize)
private val dispatcher = threadPool.asCoroutineDispatcher()
private val scope = CoroutineScope(dispatcher)

fun process(flow: Flow<String>) = flow
    .map { scope.async(expensiveHandle(it)) }
    .buffer(threadPoolSize)
    .map { it.await() }
    .flowOn(dispatcher)
```

Answer (score 2):

`async` as well as `future` are extension functions of `CoroutineScope`. So, you need some
`CoroutineScope` to call them.

`runBlocking` gives some `CoroutineScope`, but it's a blocking call, so its usage in `suspend` functions [is prohibited](https://elizarov.medium.com/blocking-threads-suspending-coroutines-d33e11bf4761).

You may go with `GlobalScope.async`, but it's also [not recommended](https://elizarov.medium.com/the-reason-to-avoid-globalscope-835337445abc) and execution would be dispatched by `Dispatchers.Default`, not by `threadPool.asCoroutineDispatcher()` as in original example with `CompletableFuture`.

`coroutineScope` and `withContext` functions will provide `CoroutineScope`, which inherits its `coroutineContext` from the outer scope, so flow processing will be suspended with immediately executed `expensiveHandle(it)` coroutine.

You need to create `CoroutineScope` with factory function, so that coroutines contexts won't mix:

```kotlin
fun process(flow: Flow<String>, threadPool: ThreadPoolExecutor): Flow<String> {
    val dispatcher = threadPool.asCoroutineDispatcher()
    return flow
        .map { CoroutineScope(dispatcher).async { expensiveHandle(it) } }
        .buffer(threadPool.poolSize)
        .map { it.await() }
        .flowOn(dispatcher)
}
```

Comment: If expensiveHandle() varies how long it takes to execute (e.g. making a RPC), then you could end up awaiting for the next value to complete even though there's a later value that has already finished.

For example, if you have a buffer of size 2 and the expensiveHandle calls take this long: call 1: 4s; call 2: 1s; call 3: 1s.

After 1s, call 2 will finish and you'd want call 3 to start, but it won't because you're still waiting for call 1 to finish.

Is there a way to await any value from the contents of buffer?

Comment: @MageWind, Flows are sequential by its nature. You need to wrap `it.await()` into another flow and then flatten the result, so `.map { it.await() }` need to be replaced with `.flatMapMerge { flow { emit(it.await()) } }` (see https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/flat-map-merge.html)

Comment: I arrived at a similar solution myself. It was something like: `.flatMapMerge { flow { emit(expensiveHandle()) } }`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of mapping the flow passed as argument, try returning a new flow built with the `callbackFlow` builder and collect the flow inside, so you can launch several coroutines to call `expensiveHandle(it)` and send their respective results asap.

```
fun process(flow: Flow<String>) = callbackFlow {
        flow.collect {
            launch {
                send(expensiveHandle(it))
            }
        }
    }.flowOn(threadPool.asCoroutineDispatcher())
```